# Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property * of null"

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

When running the following Vue.js page and clicking on the first button that calls the login function throws an error.  The error occurs on the call of `authenticateUser`, where `this` is `null`.  Why is that the case, and what do I need to ensure a proper `this` scope.

```vue
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-sm-center">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <form>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-12">
              <h1>Log In</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-12">
              <label for="loginEmail">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="loginEmail" placeholder="you@example.com" v-model="loginDetails.email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-12">
              <label for="loginPassword">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="loginPassword" placeholder="Password" v-model="loginDetails.password">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-12">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" @click="login">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 border-left">
        <form>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-12">
              <h1>Register free</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-12">
              <label for="registerName">Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registerName" placeholder="Your name here." v-model="registrationDetails.name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-12">
              <label for="registerEmail">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="registerEmail" placeholder="you@example.com" v-model="registrationDetails.email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-12">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" @click="register">Register</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import { authenticateUser } from '../axios/calls'

export default class Login extends Vue {
  public loginDetails = {
    email: '',
    password: ''
  };

  public registrationDetails = {
    name: '',
    email: ''
  };

  data () {
    return {
      loginDetails: {
        email: '',
        password: ''
      },
      registrationDetails: {
        name: '',
        email: ''
      }
    };
  }

  // Methods
  async login () {
    const res = await authenticateUser(this.loginDetails.email, this.loginDetails.password);
    return true
  }

  register () {
    return true
  }
}
</script>
```

Error follows:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'loginDetails' of null"

found in

---> <Login> at src/views/Login.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>

TypeError: Cannot read property 'loginDetails' of null
    at _callee$ (Login.vue?bb6b:90)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:293)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:118)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:32)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:21)
    at login (Login.vue?bb6b:92)
```

[Here's a photo of the screengrab, if that's helpful.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz14Z.png)

Comment: You should have a `@Component` decorator before the class declaration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58932988/vue-class-based-component-cannot-read-property-message-of-null

Comment: If you're using typescript, you should be using the vue-property-decorator plugin, so that `this` will be mapped to the component's public members. Also, if you're doing that, you will not need to declare public members AND the data.

Comment: @ffflabs Thanks, that fixed it, along with Terry's comment.

Comment: @Terry, you're both right.  I originally had vue-property-decorator included, but took it out when I couldn't figure this out.  Thanks for the helpful info as well!